# How to open HTML date input interface with react ref?

Tags: reactjs

I have a `date input` element that I want to open it's interface programmatically with React refs. Implementation provided blow didn't work.

```
function myComponent() {
  const dateRef = useRef(null);
  return (
    <>
      <input type="date" ref={dateRef} />;
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          dateRef.current.click();
        }}
      >
        Open Date Interface
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Here, when I click the button I want to open date picker interface. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was close, you can just modify the `click()` method into `showPicker()`

```
function myComponent() {
  const dateRef = useRef(null);
  return (
    <>
      <input type="date" ref={dateRef} />;
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          dateRef.current.showPicker();
        }}
      >
        Open Date Interface
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: P.S. Seems like `showPicker()` doesn't work on safari!

Comment: They opened a [webkit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=234009) about this topic. As i read online seems like `HTMLInput.showPicker` method should be supported in Safari 16. Anyway, the only way you have (now) to be sure to display a datepicker is to create a custom datepicker component by yourself